# Sequentially loading fragments at start of activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an activity that displays 4 quite content rich fragments, all of which are displayed simaltenously on screen, so starting the activity is always quite slow, as each of the fragments need to fetch data in their own separate AsyncTasks before they can be displayed.

Currently, I am loading all the fragments in the OnCreate() for IdleActivity, however this is hit-and-miss with needed objects being GC'ed to make space and is obviously not the right/best way to do it.

The fragments are always the same and are hardcoded into the layout xml for the activity

I have thought about implementing a 'queue' of sorts to load the fragments one by one in the hope that one loads its data, displays it and only then does the next fragment start being loaded. Alternatively, I could have a separate thread for each fragment responsible for starting only its fragment and then doing the whole `synchronized, notify, wait` game with them but it seems wasteful. What would be the best way of doing this?

I am unsure of how you would call the fragments to start once *after* the activity has displayed its view onto the screen because otherwise it seems like the app is hanging between activities. How would I call a method when the activity is loaded and displayed?

onCreate Code, if that is of any use:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_idle);

    showProgressDialog();

    notifFrag = (notifFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_notif);
    forecastFrag = new forecastFragment();
    currentInfoFrag = new currentInfoFragment();
    calendarFrag = new calendarFragment();

    notifDisplayHandler = new Handler();
    weatherUpdateHandler = new Handler();
    calendarUpdateHandler = new Handler();

    hideProgressDialog();
}
```

The Threads that handle content:

```
private final Runnable notifUpdateThread = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        //Display the notifications
        //Index is handled internally by the fragment
        notifFrag.displayNotifsView();
        Log.i(TAG, "Notification Thread runs update");
        //Display each notif for 10 seconds
        notifDisplayHandler.postDelayed(notifUpdateThread, 10000);
    }
};
private currentInfoFragment currentInfoFrag;
private forecastFragment forecastFrag;
private final Runnable weatherUpdateThread = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        //The callbacks for these are implemented in the respective fragments
        // so calling this updates the fragments as well
        currentInfoFrag.updateWeather(IdleActivity.this);
        forecastFrag.updateWeather(IdleActivity.this);

        Log.i(TAG, "Weather Thread runs updates");

        //Refreshes weather data every 20 minutes
        weatherUpdateHandler.postDelayed(weatherUpdateThread, 1200000);
    }
};
private calendarFragment calendarFrag;
private final Runnable calendarUpdateThread = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        calendarFrag.populateCalendar(IdleActivity.this);

        Log.i(TAG, "Calendar Thread runs update");
        //Run next update in 4 Hours
        calendarUpdateHandler.postDelayed(calendarUpdateThread, 14400000);
    }
};
```

The threads are started when activity is attached to window:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    //Handle loading of content
    notifDisplayHandler.postDelayed(notifUpdateThread, 10000);
    weatherUpdateHandler.post(weatherUpdateThread);
    calendarUpdateHandler.post(calendarUpdateThread);
}
```

Structure:

```
IdleActivity
   -CalendarFragment
   -CurrentWeatherFragment
   -ForecastFragment
   -NotificationsFragment
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are using Viewpager?

Comment: No Viewpager, should have clarified, the fragments are being loaded into the activity to be displayed simaltenously

Comment: Can u POST some of your code?

Comment: I've added all the relevant code but I'm not sure of what help it will be

Comment: All the fragments are displayed at same time? If not then you can do your work for each fragment only when you are viewing fragment. There is method in fragment that loads content when they are visible on screen. Can you POST screenshot of your activity?

Comment: "_all of which are displayed simaltenously on screen_"